# dayClick adds events to all days in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullcalendar

Am currently working on fullCalendar(jQuery Plugin) and i stuck with silly issue.

Here is my code ,

```
dayClick : function( date, jsEvent, view) {
    var eventTitle = prompt("Provide Event Title");
    if(eventTitle){
        $("#calendar").fullCalendar('renderEvent',{
            title : eventTitle,
            start : moment(date).format('HH:MM:SS'),
            stick : true
        });
    }
},
```

Issue: When user clicks on a day , it prompts for event title . After that,event gets added to all days in the calendar. I want the events to gets stick to the calendar only on the particular day.(based on user click).

Can anyone please help me to achieve this.

Comment: Please create a fiddle for more clarity..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you format the start date as only Hour/Minute/Second. Use YYYY-MM-DD in there as well.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
    var eventTitle = prompt("Provide Event Title");
    if (eventTitle) {
      $("#calendar").fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
        title: eventTitle,
        start: moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'), /* vs HH:MM:SS */
        stick: true
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/hr9x1243/